# Last run with different options GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I've parallelized a for cycle in bash using GNU Parallel. 
This is a very simple example to show what I want to reach:

```
seq 10 | parallel -n0 echo "Hello World" &
```

I would like to detach from terminal all the run, except the last one, thus removing the & only in the last cycle.
Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
Since I was not very clear, I'll try to explain myself in a better way:

I have a simulator starting, then with GNU parallel I launch many times the same script that connect with the simulator. I want all of them detaching from the terminal except the last one to avoid confusion with overlapping output.

Comment: Why have you got `&` at the end anyway? Why not just remove it?

Comment: Because i need the first run to detach from terminal

Comment: @gabrielesani Do you understand what parallel means?

Comment: Yes, but since GNU parallel has a tons of options and you can play around with cycling arguments and so on, i wanted to know if it was any way to reach this result.

Comment: Your question is not very clear - what are you trying to do? GNU Parallel effectively runs everything as forked processes so they are not interactive with the terminal for input. Can you give a better example rather than `echo "Hello World"` showing the concept of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a simulator starting, then with parallel i launch many times the same script that connect with the simulator. I want all of them detaching from the terminal except the last one to avoid confusion with overlapping output in the terminal.

Comment: Try the `-k` option to keep the output in order - then the last one will be last.

Comment: I want only the last run to show the output.

Comment: Another option might be to declare a function that has an `if` statement inside it and discards the output to `/dev/null` unless it is the last job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for that, but default is that the first job gets /dev/tty as input. So maybe you can run your last job first?

If you just want the output and not the input then this should work:

```
seq 10 | parallel echo Hello World '> {= $_= $job->seq() == total_jobs() ? "/dev/tty" : "/dev/null" =}'
```

(Requires version 20160122 or newer)

Otherwise a workaround is to save to files and output the last file:

```
seq 10 | parallel --files -n0 echo Hello World | tail -n1 | parallel -u cat
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Installed the new version of parallel (I had the Ubuntu one, 20141022, didn't notice it was so old :D) and the first one worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.